# Running a loop to return a value that is greater than 15

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I need to run a loop that will double the initial value until it is greater than 15. I can't figure out how to get it to stop at the value I want. This is the code I have so far.

```
def while1(initial):
    total = 1
    while initial < 15:
        total = initial * 2
    return total


print while1(3)  # -> 24
print while1(2)  # -> 16
print while1(15)  # -> 15
```

It isn't returning the values I want.

Comment: So, you're checking if initial is greater than 15, but where is the part where you store a bigger number in initial?

Comment: Try to debug your code. One way to do that is to print the value of `initial` and `total` inside your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have there is constantly checking whether or not `initial` is less than 15, but then changing total, and not initial. Python has a nice 'command' `*=`, which can be used to multiply a variable by some number, and then save the answer back in the variable. You can use this as follows:

```
def while1(initial):
    while initial < 16: #Are we done yet? (Remember to run when initial is equal to 15)
        initial *= 2 #Double initial
    return initial #This will only run when initial is greater than 15
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

`initial` never change, so your while loop never quits, use `total` as condition variable:

```
def while1(initial):
    total = initial
    while total < 15:
        total = total * 2
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can calculate the result directly, without any loop:

```
import math

def double_until_greater_than_15(x):
    return x * 2**math.ceil(max(math.log2(16 / x), 0))

print(double_until_greater_than_15(3)) # 24
print(double_until_greater_than_15(2)) # 16
print(double_until_greater_than_15(15)) # 30
```